# StringTemplate: increment value when if condition true

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I want to find out if StringTemplate have/support incrementation of a number.
Situation is:

**input:** is an array of objects which have "`isKey()` and `getName()`" getter.
output should be (`i=0; IF !obj.getKey() THEN ps.setObject(i++,obj.getName)) ENDIF`):

```
ps.setObject(1,"Name");  
ps.setObject(2,"Name");  
ps.setObject(3,"Name");  
...
```

**Currently I have next ST**: `<objs:{<if(it.key)><else>ps.setObject(<i>, <it.name;>);<"\n"><endif>}>`
And the output in case if 1st is key:

```
ps.setObject(2,"Name");  
ps.setObject(3,"Name");  
ps.setObject(4,"Name");  
...
```

Issue now I need to find a way to replace the 'i' with something which will be increment only when if condition is true.

PLS advice who faced this kind of issue!

Answer (score 0):

In general, changing the state in response to ST's getting the state is not a good idea, so numbering non-key fields should happen in your model, *before* you start with the generation.

Add a getter for `nonKeyIndex` to the class of your model that hosts the `name` property. Go through all siblings, and number them as you need (i.e. starting from one and skipping the keys in your numbering). Now you can use this ST to produce the desired output:

```
<objs:{<if(it.key)><else>ps.setObject(<it.nonKeyIndex>, <it.name;>);<"\n"><endif>}>
```

Sometimes it may not be possible to add methods such as `nonKeyIndex` to your model classes. In such cases you should wrap your classes into view classes designed specifically to work with string template, and add the extra properties there:

```
public class ColumnView {
    private final Column c;
    private int nonKeyIdx;
    public ColumnView(Column c) {this.c = c;}
    public String getName() { return c.getName(); }
    public boolean getKey() { return c.getKey(); }
    public int getNonKeyIndex() { return nonKeyIdx; }
    public void setNonKeyIndex(int i) { nonKeyIdx = i; }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response, this was kind of approach was a backup plan for me. Also I was hopping that ST will have any support for this cases. If to prepare all input manually just for print then, IMHO, StringTemplate is not so conformable.

Comment: @SairuS This is the correct approach, in view of ST's adherence to the MVC pattern. This is how I did it back at my last job that used ST.

Comment: @SairuS "If to prepare all input manually just for print then, IMHO, StringTemplate is not so conformable" The idea of ST is to move the output dependency away from your code and into your runtime. You can design your model once (i.e. "do all input manually") and then write multiple STs to produce C++, Java, and HTML docs for your project, all without changing a single line of your Java code.